# Vue pass v-on to subelement inside component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Imagine a component with the following HTML structure:

```
<template>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="innerRow">
         <div class="outterLabel">
            <label class="labelCss">{{label}}</label>
         </div>
         <div class="outterField">
            <span style="float: none; position: absolute;">
               <select ref="selectField">
                  <option v-for="item in list">{{item.name}}</option>
               </select>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

When I use this component I would like to pass `v-on` events but I want them to be attached to the `<select>` element and not to the `<div>` at the top. Is there a way to achieve this in Vue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the listeners will be attached to the root element. This is the default behaviour. To change this you can make use of [`$listeners`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners) option.

So to make it possible attach the listeners to the `select` element as follows:

```
<select v-on="$listeners" ref="selectField">
  <option v-for="item in list">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Now you can attach event listeners directly on your custom select component

```
<my-select v-on:change="doSomething"></my-select>
```

For more info check out - [Building fully transparent wrapper components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components)

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was needing.